# Which version of Lubuntu should I use?

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, intel, compatibility, eeepc

I want to install a light distro on my netbook. (It currently has an out of date distro which is not upgradeable.) Here are the specs:

- eEE pc 4g GLAXY, LINUX 4g SSD, 512MB DDR2
- Intel Mobile cpu & Chipset
- WI-FI 802, 11B/G  10/100MBPS ETHERNET, 0.3 m CAMERA

Which Lubuntu should I use please?

Will everything work--including wireless?

Comment: What I would recommend is that you get a LiveCD of the latest Lubuntu release and run it on your computer via USB (don't install it). If everything works fine after a couple of minutes or hours of use, then you are good to go.

Comment: ok- that sounds easy. Will it run easily from the usb key? It's not a computer but a little netbook

Comment: @Trisha It will run.you need to prepare a live usb using `unetbootin` (for all platforms) or `LILI` (for preparing in windows machine)

Comment: You should have no problem with the latest Lubuntu Release :)

Comment: did the above but netbook wont boot from USB stick which is what I suspected.

Comment: ok- learnt how to boot from usb key - but discovered I downloaded Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu for the OS! Off to start again...

Answer (score 3):

## Lubuntu 12.04 32-bit

The latest  version of lubuntu will support in your hardware. [Download it right now.](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/precise/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso) :-)

Comment: Just FYI: "Unlike Ubuntu, Lubuntu 12.04 is not a LTS, this version will be supported for 18 months." http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1204-now-available

Answer (score 1):

Precise Pangolin of course.
Download it from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/).
[Here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) you have USB Pendrive, it would help to install from usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be sure to install the 32-bit version of Lubuntu.

Your hardware should work completely without issue, but the install size of Lubuntu will come close to consuming your whole SSD.  This is dangerous because Lubuntu is not as light as you might think it is.  Once you open a couple of tabs with the default installed Chromium, you will be swapping to disk.

By default, the installer will partition a 512MB swap partition, leaving you with less than 3.2 GB hard drive space after being formatted.

It's gonna be a hard road.  Good luck.  :)